# Concatenate variables in ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, jinja2

i'm trying to do the following task:

```
 -name: Dump Server1 database to Server2

  shell: 'mysqldump -h {{ server1_ip }} -u {{ mysql_user }} --protocol=tcp --password={{ mysql_passwd }} --single-transaction --set-gtid-purged=off {{server1_db}} table1 table2 table3 > dump.sql'
```

the idea of this task is to export database structure and the data of the tables that i want. In this example i only put 3 tables, but in real life it could be 20 or 30 tables. So, my idea is de do something like this:

replace "table1 table2 table3 for something like "{{ tables }}" and then do a variable with multiple values, something like that:

```
tables:
  - table1
  - table2
  - table3

...
```

anyone knows the right way to do something like that? put a variable in the sentence and replace for a concatenation of the multiple values from a variable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `tables` as a list like:

```
tables:
  - table1
  - table2
  - table3
```

Then doing `{{ tables | join(' ') }}` will generate `table1 table2 table3`.

See [other useful filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) in the docs.

Comment: I tried this but it's not done correctly.

i put ...{{ item | join(" ") }}...
with_items:
  - 'table1'
  - 'table2'

I see in the error that it's interpreting t a b l e 1 instead table1 table2

Comment: Why do you use `with_items`? Just put `{{ tables | join(' ') }}` where you'd otherwise insert space-separated tables' names.